# History of the World Pt. 2

Tags: history-of-the-world-1

What ever happened to History of the World Pt. 2, from Mel Brooks? Pt. 1 was really funny and at the end of the movie there is a trailer for the second part, but from all of my research, I cannot seem to find out what happened. Part 1 came out in the 80's, so I feel like part 2 should have come out by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's a joke.** There were no plans for a sequel. This is explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_World,_Part_I#Previews_of_coming_attractions):

> Despite the preview, no sequel has been released, and the “Part I” of the film’s title is merely a historical joke (*The History of the World* was a book about the ancient history of Greece and Rome, written by Sir Walter Raleigh while prisoner in the Tower of London; he had only managed to complete the first volume before being beheaded).

Comment: Darn, I was really looking forward to Hitler ice-skating and the jews in space. Oh well, thanks.

Comment: Well, Brooks *kind of* followed up on the Jews in Space idea 6 years later in *Spaceballs*, esp. with Yogurt.

Comment: Oh ya, I forgot about that. That was a good movie as well. MAY THE SCHWARTZ BE WITH YOU! is one of my favorite lines in it.

Comment: And he _kind of_ got his Hitler jokes in during the musical play "Springtime for Hitler" in the Producers.

Comment: OK, so the joke now is that an **actual** _History of the World Part II_ is in production as a Hulu TV series, because nobody _anywhere_ can leave _anything_ alone.